# .NET Core Web API Backend and Angular/ReactJS Frontend deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, amazon-eks

We are planning create a new project with .net core web api backend and Angular/React frontend.

We have couple of questions about deployment in AWS,

1. what is the best deployment solution for this type of microservice project?
2. Does .net core web api can deploy in AWS Amazon Linux with nginx?
3. is it possible to use docker and eks to make deployment?
4. is there any tutorial, videos and docs for this topic?

Answer (score 1):

One option you have for AWS and .NET is developing a serverless architecture app. You can refer to the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) for a .NET app example.

The Photo Asset Management (PAM) example app uses Amazon Rekognition to categorize images, which are stored with Amazon S3 Intelligent-Tiering for cost savings. Users can upload new images that are analyzed with label detection. Those labels are then stored in an Amazon DynamoDB table. Users can later request a bundle of images associated with a list of labels. When images are requested, they are retrieved from Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), zipped, and the user is sent a link to download the resulting zip file.

The frontend is a single React app that uses the Cloudscape Design System. With the React app, users can authenticate with an Amazon Cognito flow. The app is deployed to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket using the provided AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) stacks. It is publicly exposed by using an Amazon CloudFront distribution. The name is dynamically created during the AWS CDK deployment.

See:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_csharp_3_topic.html)